# Como versionar arquivos estáticos/binários (imagens, PDFs e etc.) eficientemente?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, versionamento, documentação

Por exemplo tenho um arquivo em PDF com um conteúdo e após modifico algumas coisas nele, como devo proceder em questão das versões? (Por algum motivo devo versionar esse arquivo).

E no caso das imagens, onde eu tenho essa situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E após eu tenho isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Devo então versionar as imagens usando o **versionamento semântico** em relação ao conteúdo das imagens ou apenas crio um versão para cada imagem independente do conteúdo, como por ex.: **imagem 01** — v. 1, **imagem 02** — v. 2?

Comment: O importante é versionar de alguma maneira. O nome é bom, e um cabeçalho no documento também é muito bom. Além disso, use um repositório, como *git* ou *team system* por exemplo, que vai gerenciar todas as versões que você atualizar

Comment: Será que essa pergunta realmente é baseado em opiniões? Eu também tenho essa dúvida.... Além das sugestões dadas pelo @RicardoPontual, eu também poderia sugerir uma ferramenta profissional, se chama [Confluence](https://br.atlassian.com/software/confluence)

Comment: @MarceloBoni acredito que seja, porque não existe um padrão. Se fosse um escopo menor, por exemplo *"como versionar um documento no git"* acho que seria uma resposta de consenso, mas ela é bem genérica, vai ter mais sugestões que uma resposta assertiva, pelo menos eu ach

Comment: Acho que com uma boa edição a pergunta será completamente válida. Se for alterada, por exemplo, para **Como versionar arquivos binários eficientemente**. Acho uma dúvida super válida.